# Why are common table expressions faster even when limiting the result?

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, common-table-expression

I can't get my head around why the following query:

```
SELECT ref,
article_number,
count(article_number)
FROM invoice
INNER JOIN goods_list USING (invoice_number)
WHERE invoice_owner = 'someone'
GROUP BY invoice_number, article_number
LIMIT 1
```

is way slower than this one:

```
WITH base_data AS (
    SELECT invoice_number
    FROM invoice
    WHERE invoice_owner = 'someone'
    LIMIT 1
)

SELECT invoice_number,
    article_number,
    count(article_number)
FROM base_data
INNER JOIN goods_list USING (invoice_number)
GROUP BY invoice_number, article_number
```

Is the limit applied after the whole result set is returned?

Comment: The code is clearly not MySQL, because MySQL does not support CTEs.  I removed that tag.

Comment: Just look at the table size being `JOIN`ed - the second example has one row to join whereas the first example has to check all rows of invoice.

Comment: Post the tables schema and the output of `explain analyze`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query processes *all* the data for the invoice owner.  It does the `group by` and *finally* returns one row.

The second query gets one row in the CTE for the invoice owner up front.  It joins that single row into another table and then does the aggregation on way fewer rows.

Hence, it is not surprising that the second query is much faster, because it is processing many fewer rows for the aggregation.

Note:  when using `limit` you should also use `order by`.  Otherwise, you can get any matching row when the code runs -- and you might even get different rows on different runs.

Comment: Also try using `explain analyze` to compare both query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915209/how-to-understand-an-explain-analyze