# Feature engineering using PostgreSQL on a large dataset (~3M entries)

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, machine-learning, bigdata

I have a dataset of ~3 million chess games (existing columns include names of players, date, result and tournament name). I want to use Random Forest to predict results of chess games.

To this end, I want to do some feature engineering. There are several variables that I believe would be strong predictors, e.g. players' results so far in the tournament, number of games 90 days prior to the game.

Columns:

```
 - date DATE  
 - namew TEXT  
 - nameb TEXT  
 - whiterank INTEGER  
 - blackrank INTEGER  
 - tournament TEXT  
 - t_round INTEGER  
 - result REAL  
 - id BIGINT  
 - chess_data2_pkey(id)
```

Indices:

```
game_index INDEX chess_data2 (namew ASC, tournament ASC, date ASC)
```

Unfortunately, my queries were rather slow (I wrote 14 and tested them on a smaller dataset, not even 1 was completed in 8 days). Below is a simplified version, which I put on 2 hours ago and still have no results.

```
SELECT Sum(result) 
INTO   temp 
FROM   chess_data2 t1 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT t2.id 
              FROM   chess_data2 t2 
              WHERE  t1.tournament = t2.tournament 
                AND  t1.namew = t2.namew 
                AND  t1.date < t2.date)
```

My questions:

1. **Can I make this work faster in SQL** (faster as in, complete 14 similar queries in less than 10 days on my i7-4710HQ and 12gb of RAM?). Perhaps by explicitly sorting it beforehand?
2. **Any other way I could achieve my goal faster?** I tried to naively code this using loops in Python and the performance was even worse, but I heard C is better for this stuff - but just how much better?

I use Python 3.5 for estimation and psycopg2 to deal with SQL.

**EDIT:** Thank you all for helpful responses. I managed to successfully use indexes to make some of the queries extremely fast, e.g. this one:

```
# Number of points that the white player has so far accrued throughout the tournament
(SELECT coalesce(SUM(result),0) from chess_data2 t2
where (t1.namew = t2.namew) and t1.tournament = t2.tournament
and t1.date > t2.date  and t1.date < t2.date + 90)
+ SELECT coalesce(SUM(1-result),0) from chess_data2 t2
where (t1.namew = t2.nameb) and t1.tournament = t2.tournament
and t1.date > t2.date and t1.date < t2.date + 90 ) AS result_in_t_w
from chessdata2 t1
```

Takes only ~60 seconds now, which is more than acceptable. However, for some reason, the counting selects like this one take more than half an hour (I didn't wait longer) to compute:

```
# Number of games that the white player has so far played in the tournament
(SELECT count(*) from chess_data t2 where (t1.namew = t2.namew) and
t1.tournament = t2.tournament and t1.date > t2.date and t1.date < t2.date + 90)
+ (SELECT coalesce(count(*),0) from chess_data2 t2
where (t1.namew = t2.nameb) and t1.tournament = t2.tournament
and t1.date > t2.date and t1.date < t2.date + 90) AS games_t_w from chess_data2 t1
```

I guess I'm using the indexes in the wrong way but I have no idea what's wrong, it's basically the same thing as previously but instead of summing result column I calculate sum of rows... Does it make sense at all?

Comment: You should check `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` when trying to improve query performace. [**READ**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915209/how-to-understand-an-explain-analyze)

Comment: Can we see your database schema and defined indexes?

Comment: @halfer I added information about columns and indeces (copied from pycharm), is that what you were expecting?

Comment: Yep, that's good. Do you not have a primary key index on `id`?

Comment: Nope, we used "UPDATE chess_data2 SET id = DEFAULT". So I guess I should run ALTER TABLE chess_data2 ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)? On it.

Comment: If it is unique, then yes - then try your query again.

Comment: After indexing and adding primary key I tried the following query: "SELECT (SELECT coalesce(SUM(result),0) FROM chess_data2 t2 WHERE (t1.nameW = t2.nameW) and t1.tournament = t2.tournament and t1.date > t2.date) INTO temp FROM chess_data2 t1"
So far it took around 10-15 minutes and it didn't finish but I guess I can wait through the night to at least see if it will take hours or days. Will post an update. Thanks for helping out so far!

Comment: Hey, that actually did help! Well to some extent at least... I was able to get the sum() queries working, but for some reason the count() queries do not work as well... any idea how to proceed (see my edit for details)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want speed up executing query you can create index of columns use to joining (foreign keys and columns using where clausule).
But added index cause slow down inserting and updtating, and increase required to space disc.

Comment: Hey, that actually did help! Well to some extent at least... I was able to get the sum() queries working, but for some reason the count() queries do not work as well... any idea how to proceed (see my edit for details)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure know why you use that IN. I thnk you try to simplify your query and lost more of the logic.

I belive that is equivalent to

```
SELECT sum(result) INTO temp 
FROM chess_data2 t1
```

You probably want

```
SELECT tournament, namew, sum(result) 
FROM chess_data2 t1 
GROUP BY tournament, namew
```

or

```
SELECT tournament, namew, sum(result) 
FROM chess_data2 t1 
WHERE tournament = @tournament
  AND namew = @namew
```

Comment: I put a simplified version to acoid a lengthy query, but there is also a t1.date < t2.date in the WHERE clause. Any way to use GROUP BY and include this? I edited the question to reflect this, mb.

Comment: did you check `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` ? We need you provide db schema sample data and expected result, otherwise is just a guessing game.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Also did you create index on your table?

Comment: Well, I tried my best to make the question understandable, it is a bit hard when I'm a beginner to SQL :)  
I didn't index it, I started a few minutes ago as per suggestion by Abihabi87.
I'm still fighting the syntax errors, but so far I made this: CREATE INDEX game_index ON (namew, nameb, tournament, date)

Comment: check [**HERE**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp)  We dont mind to help, but we arent a school. You should try follow a tutorial first.

Comment: I indexed over namew, tournament and date. What sort of % improvement can I expect?

Comment: Oh my god ... how should I know? You didnt show us your query or your explain analyze. The right index should make it almost instant, so even a regular index should improve a lot.

Comment: Nice, I'll need to look into the EXPLAIN ANALYZE stuff and come back with an update, thx for the suggestions!

Comment: Hey, that actually did help! Well to some extent at least... I was able to get the sum() queries working, but for some reason the count() queries do not work as well... any idea how to proceed (see my edit for details)?