# How to query max and min records of every 5 seconds (or any other user-defined period) within a selected period of time in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres 9.6 table with hundreds of millions of records in 'prices' table with only four columns: uid, price, unit, dt. dt is a datetime in standard format like '2017-05-01 00:00:00.585' with fractions of a second. It might be none to dozens record each second.

I can find MAX and MIN price record in some time period. I can quite easily select a period using

```
SELECT date_trunc('second', dt) as time, min(price), max(price)
FROM prices
WHERE dt >= '2017-05-01 00:00:00' AND dt < '2017-05-01 00:00:59'
GROUP BY time
ORDER BY time;
```

But date_trunc does not have flexibility and does not allow to set arbitrary period, for example 5 seconds, or 10 minutes. Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `generate_series` to get the ranges on the interval of time you need to search. Then use `dd + '5 seconds'::interval` to get the upper bound of the range

In this example we look for one day of data every 5 seconds

```
WITH ranges as (
    SELECT dd as start_range, 
           dd + '5 seconds'::interval as end_range, 
           ROW_NUMBER() over () as grp
    FROM generate_series
            ( '2017-05-01 00:00:00'::timestamp 
            , '2017-05-02 00:00:00'::timestamp
            , '5 seconds'::interval) dd
), create_grp as (
    SELECT r.grp, r.start_range, r.end_range, p.price
    FROM prices p
    JOIN ranges r
      ON p.date >= r.start_range
     AND p.date < r.end_range
)        
SELECT grp, start_range, end_range, MIN(price), MAX(price)
FROM create_grp
GROUP BY grp, start_range, end_range
ORDER BY grp
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works! Looks like an SQL PhD answer! :-) I'm quite new to SQL. Would you mind to explain how it works?

Comment: What part? Try `SELECT * FROM ranges` so you see the result

Comment: More like what and where I should add, in order to see what time range Min and Max values correspond to? :-)

Comment: Try again, I copy paste from above and there isnt alias `r` below

Comment: where you put the `WHERE` ?? try with a composite index `(unit, date)`

Comment: Sorry I just read you already have composite index. I need see the query and the [explain plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915209/how-to-understand-an-explain-analyze)

Comment: Although, as soon as I add WHERE clause to it, performance drops to unbearable. Table has uid, unit (effectively product_id), price, dt (date). I add WHERE unit='XXXX' after JOIN  :-( I have indexes on 'unit' and 'unit and date' . without WHERE clause, it flies,  with the clause, is wait-forever execution. Any ideas? (one sec.)

Comment: You just wrote the same message I need the query and the explain analyze result.

Comment: query does not fit in the comment  characters limit :-/  I will split it on two comments.

Comment: WITH ranges as (
    SELECT dd as start_range, 
           dd + '5 seconds'::interval as end_range, 
           ROW_NUMBER() over () as grp
    FROM generate_series
            ( '2017-05-01 00:00:00'::timestamp 
            , '2017-05-02 00:00:00'::timestamp
            , '5 seconds'::interval) dd
), create_grp as (
    SELECT r.grp, r.start_range, r.end_range, p.price
    FROM prices p
    JOIN ranges r
      ON p.date >= r.start_range
     AND p.date < r.end_range
    WHERE unit='AABBCC'
)

Comment: SELECT grp, start_range, end_range, MIN(price), MAX(price)
FROM create_grp
GROUP BY grp, start_range, end_range
ORDER BY grp

Comment: You could edit the question ;P Also show me your create index.

Comment: adding WHERE unit='AABBCC' makes the query runs forever. How can I optimize it to the original speed? (without WHERE clause was super quick)
I'm grabbing the Explaing resulting before modifications and after for you.

Comment: CREATE INDEX idx_dt_instrument
    ON public.prices USING btree
    (date, unit COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

Comment: try creating another index but invert the fields to `(unit, date)` and try again. Also is the unit already in the same collate? otherwise that would cause some problem.

Comment: Done. CREATE INDEX idx_instrument_dt
    ON public.prices USING btree
    (instrument COLLATE pg_catalog."default", dt)
    TABLESPACE pg_default; Same story: indefinite query. I can post explain before and after (without new index) in 4 posts. (stackoverflow message  chars limit)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155009/discussion-between-juan-carlos-oropeza-and-uzla).

Comment: Before: GroupAggregate  (cost=2909165506.27..3006889539.60 rows=8000000 width=40)
  Group Key: create_grp.grp, create_grp.start_range, create_grp.end_range
  CTE ranges
    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.00..25.00 rows=1000 width=24)
          ->  Function Scan on generate_series dd  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=8)
  CTE create_grp
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=117649.05..827926115.50 rows=6509602222 width=47)
          ->  CTE Scan on ranges r  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=24)
          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on prices p  (cost=117649.05..762830.08 rows=6509602 width=31)

Comment: Recheck Cond: ((dt >= r.start_range) AND (dt < r.end_range))
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_dt_instrument  (cost=0.00..116021.65 rows=6509602 width=0)
                      Index Cond: ((dt >= r.start_range) AND (dt < r.end_range))
  ->  Sort  (cost=2081239365.77..2097513371.32 rows=6509602222 width=40)
        Sort Key: create_grp.grp, create_grp.start_range, create_grp.end_rage
        ->  CTE Scan on create_grp  (cost=0.00..130192044.44 rows=6509602222 width=40)

Comment: After adding WHERE (before new index): GroupAggregate  (cost=1029283508.90..1060020480.57 rows=8000000 width=40)
  Group Key: create_grp.grp, create_grp.start_range, create_grp.end_range
  CTE ranges
    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.00..25.00 rows=1000 width=24)
          ->  Function Scan on generate_series dd  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=8)
  CTE create_grp
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=344299.48..448807971.73 rows=2043798111 width=47)
          Join Filter: ((p.dt >= r.start_range) AND (p.dt < r.end_range))
          ->  CTE Scan on ranges r  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=24)

Comment: ->  Materialize  (cost=344299.48..1339476.69 rows=18394183 width=31)
                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on prices p  (cost=344299.48..1121763.77 rows=18394183 width=31)
                      Recheck Cond: ((unit)::text = 'AABBCC'::text)
                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_instrument  (cost=0.00..339700.94 rows=18394183 width=0)
                            Index Cond: ((unit)::text = 'AABBCC'::text)
  ->  Sort  (cost=580475512.17..585585007.45 rows=2043798111 width=40)

Comment: Sort Key: create_grp.grp, create_grp.start_range, create_grp.end_range
        ->  CTE Scan on create_grp  (cost=0.00..40875962.22 rows=2043798111 width=40)

Comment: Join me in CHAT

Comment: Man, I'd rather discus it privatively and post result here. This comment system is 'far from ideal' to say the least...