# PostgreSQL Explain Plan Operators

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan

When I type:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
from TABLE
```

I can see the execution plan. What I would like is some sort of PostgreSQL documentation that is going on in each part of the execution plan.

I know how to read an execution plan; however, there are some things in the execution plan that I don't recognize such as APPEND, so I just wanted to see an actual PostgreSQL document.

Anyone know of a reference?

I can only find a list for SQL Server, which is close, but not what I want. Basically, I am looking for the PostgreSQL version of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/showplan-logical-and-physical-operators-reference?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: So you are familiar with https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html already?

Comment: You should almost always use the additional options, like `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` to get the whole picture. A plan is just a plan and you can't see if it's a good or bad one. That's where the details come in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is PostgreSQL explain telling me exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117262/what-is-postgresql-explain-telling-me-exactly) or [How to understand an EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915209/how-to-understand-an-explain-analyze)

Comment: @Bergi The PG docs don't explain what, for example, "Append" or "Bitmap Heap Scan" do.

Comment: I found https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/how-to-interpret-postgresql-explain-analyze-output/ and https://www.pgmustard.com/docs/explain pretty helpful

Comment: @Schwern True, but searching the docs finds some explanations for the terms in various places, e.g. on [appends](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/parallel-plans.html#PARALLEL-APPEND) and [bitmap scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/indexes-bitmap-scans.html)

Comment: try [Explaining_EXPLAIN.pdf](https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/4/45/Explaining_EXPLAIN.pdf) or: use https://explain.dalibo.com/ perhaps?

Comment: Not sure why my question was closed, it's not a duplicate question.

Comment: @ChickenSandwichNoPickles Could say more about what you're asking that is different from the other question?

Comment: @Schwern He's looking for a list of the operators (or steps) that can occur in an `EXPLAIN` output, with explanation of what they mean, not for a general "how to read/parse the `explain` output". It might be slightly off-topic asking for a list, but it's not a duplicate of the question I had suggested.

Comment: Exactly!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!